# STL C++11: std::regex issue on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/* check run time */
class MKLClock
{
public:
    MKLClock() : _start(time(nullptr))
    {
        std::cout << "start: " << std::endl;
    }

    ~MKLClock()
    {
        std::cout << "end: " << difftime(time(nullptr), _start) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    time_t _start;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    static std::regex _regex_text_uri = std::regex(R"((([a-zA-Z0-9\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\%_\`\{\|\}\~\.]+@)?)(((ftp|https?):\/\/)?[-\w]+\.([-\w]+\.)*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+|[-A-Za-z]+)(:\d+)?(((\/([A-Za-z0-9-\._~:\/\?\#\[\]\@\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=])*)+)\??([A-Za-z0-9-\._~:\/\?\#\[\]\@\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=\%])*)?)([^A-Za-z]|$))", std::regex_constants::icase); /* regex text */

    std::string string  = "\n\r aa sdfsadfsafa asfasf \nasdfasd: asf_sdf@google.com as\nfasdf http://www.google.com/asdfsdaf/asf/aa.htm?a=d&a=b asdfasdf"; /* normal text */

    std::string string1 = "CCCCCClentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetch  \n\n\ntest.text uploaded a file\n  AAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchAAABBBBBCdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetchdoSilentFetch"; /* long text */

    MKLClock *clock = new MKLClock();
    std::sregex_iterator pos(string.cbegin(), string.cend(), _regex_text_uri);
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    std::cout << "normal text: " << std::endl;
    for ( ; pos != end; ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << pos->str() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    delete clock;

    MKLClock *clock1 = new MKLClock();
    std::sregex_iterator pos1(string1.cbegin(), string1.cend(), _regex_text_uri);
    std::sregex_iterator end1;
    std::cout << "long text: " << std::endl;
    for ( ; pos1 != end1; ++pos1)
    {
        std::cout << pos1->str() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    delete clock1;

    return 0;
} /* main */
```

The regex text can hangup string1 for a long time.

if wrote such regex text: ((ftp|https?)://)?[-\w]+.
   std::regex can hangup for a long time, but if add \b to regex text like this: \b((ftp|https?)://)?[-\w]+., it work fine.

Can anyone explain why std::regex can not parse ((ftp|https?)://)?[-\w]+., but javascript can parse it, I tested on pcre, it work fine too.
Is it std::regex issue?

Comment: Your `string1` is quite a long text, it takes time to for regex to work on this long line.

Comment: But if i add \b, it only spent 1ms, but original spent 26s.

Comment: My point is, `std::regex` does parse correctly (although slow), while you claim "std::regex can not parse".